Stopped supermartingale bounded below
I'm reading the proof of this theorem (Robbins-Siegmund) and I don't understand why it is said that a supermartingale is bounded from below.
So, it is said that the sequence $(Y_n)_{n\ge1}$ is a supermartingale, defined as $$Y_n=V_n'-\sum^{n-1}_{i=1}(\chi_i'-\eta_i'),$$ where $V_n'=\alpha_{n-1}V_n$, $\chi_n'=\alpha_n\chi_n$, $\eta_n'=\alpha_n\eta_n$ and $\alpha_n=\frac1{\prod^n_{k=1}(1+\beta_k)}$. Here the sequences $(V_n)_{n\ge1}, (\beta_n)_{n\ge1}, (\chi_n)_{n\ge1}$ and $(\eta_n)_{n\ge1}$ are all positive and adapted to a filtration $\mathbb{F}$. Moreover it is assumed that $$\mathbb{E}[V_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]\le V_n(1+\beta_n)+\chi_n-\eta_n.$$
We define the stopping time $T_a=\inf_{n\ge1}\{\sum^n_{i=1}(\chi_i'-\eta_i')\ge a\}$, for $a>0$. By the stopping theorem, $Y_{\min(n,T_a)}$ is a supermartingale. I want to understand, why the text says that it is bounded from below by $-a$:

If $n<T_a$, by def. $\sum^n_{i=1}(\chi_i'-\eta_i')<a$, hence $$Y_{\min(n,T_a)}=Y_n=V_n'-\sum^{n-1}_{i=1}(\chi_i'-\eta_i')>V_n'-a+(\chi_n'-\eta_n')\ge\mathbb{E}[V_{n+1}'|\mathcal{F}_n]-a\ge -a\quad\text{a.s.}$$

But if $n\ge T_a$, by def. $\sum^n_{i=1}(\chi_i'-\eta_i')\ge a$, hence $$Y_{\min(n,T_a)}=Y_{T_a}=V_{T_a}'-\sum^{{T_a}-1}_{i=1}(\chi_i'-\eta_i')\le V_{T_a}'-a+(\chi_{T_a}'-\eta_{T_a}'),$$ but $$V_{T_a}'-a+(\chi_{T_a}'-\eta_{T_a}')\ge \mathbb{E}[V_{{T_a}+1}'|\mathcal{F}_n]-a\ge -a\quad\text{a.s.}$$


Hence, the latter case is not enough to conclude that the supermartingale is always bounded below by $-a$, am I wrong?


From the definition, we have
$$ Y_{n \wedge T_a} = V_{n\wedge T_a}' - \sum_{i=1}^{n\wedge T_n -1}  (\chi_i'-\eta_i') \geq 0 -a = -a$$
since $ V_{n\wedge T_a}' \geq 0$ and $  \sum_{i=1}^{n\wedge T_n -1}  (\chi_i'-\eta_i') < a $ because $n\wedge T_a -1 \leq T_a$ and by the definition of $T_a$. Does this answer your question?

Thank you, I didn't visualize it that way, but this seems indeed right. So, basically my procedure was not wrong but just inconclusive.
